# Protect multiple sheets excel and maintain the protection until password re-entered

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which does protect multiple sheets at once but when I re-open the file, the protection is gone. How can I maintain this when my file is uploaded to SharePoint. However, in future I should alone be able to re-enter password to make changes.

OR

Show me any other way I can make this sheet read-only for others (they can not edit it even if they try).

```
Sub protect_all_sheets()
top:
pass = InputBox("password?")
repass = InputBox("Verify Password")
If Not (pass = repass) Then
MsgBox "you made a boo boo"
GoTo top
End If
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
If Worksheets(i).ProtectContents = True Then GoTo oops
Next
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
s.Protect Password:=pass
Next
Exit Sub
oops: MsgBox "I think you have some sheets that are already protected. Please unprotect all sheets then running this Macro."
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: The workbook needs to be saved after protecting a sheet.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Yes obviously, I saved the macro and the workbook. But when I open it the code is gone, and sheets are unlocked.

Comment: @Phylogenesis It worked now. Thank you :)